# Starting QProcess inside a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qprocess

I have been struggling with this basic problem for a while now.
I’m trying to start a `QProcess` from a thread. Starting the process works fine and the process runs correctly but my problem is that the `finished()` signal is never emitted.

Here is my example:

My class variables are

```
std::atomic<bool>  recording;
QProcess proc;
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> recordingThread;
```

The class:

```
Recorder::Recorder(ParentClass *parent): QObject(parent){

    connect(&proc,SIGNAL(finished(int)),this,SLOT(finishedFFMPEG())); 
}

void Recorder::start(){

    if (!recordingThread){
        recording = true;
        recordingThread.reset(new std::thread(&Recorder::recordThread, this));
    }
}

void Recorder::recordThread(){

    while(recording){
        //writing frame
    }
    proc.start("C:\\ffmpeg.exe", QStringList() <<"-i"<< picDir.c_str() << "-r"<< "30" << "-vcodec"<< "ffv1" << filename.c_str());
    proc.waitForStarted();      
}

void Recorder::stop(){

    if (recordingThread) {
        recording = false;
        recordingThread->join(); recordingThread.reset();  
    }
}

void Recorder::finishedFFMPEG(){
    qDebug() << "finished";
}
```

`start()` and `stop()` are called from another non-GUI thread in my `ParentClass`.

I tried everything from using pointers, running my `recordThread()` as a `QThread` and starting the `QProcess` in the `stop()` function but I simply never receive the `finished()` signal from the process. The process itself is being executed correctly. I know the problem lies in the different event loops.

How can I achieve my goal of starting a process after the `recordThread()` finishes and catching the `QProcess` `finished()` signal?

Comment: Is there some reason you're using std::thread instead of QThread here?

Comment: Like I said in my post, I did try using QThread but that gave me the same result.

Comment: have you thought about using `QFuture< T > QtConcurrent`? I use it as much as I can it's high level and just plain saves so much trouble + utilizes all the cores properly

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but does your thread have an event loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot say that I am very surprised that your construct does not work. You execute the member function recordThread() with std::thread in a different thread. So far so good. In recordThread() you have a loop, which looks like it collects/creates/writes frames. As soon as the loop is left, the frames are passed to ffmpeg via a QProcess. At least this is your intention. Did I get this right?

Now, in stop() you clear the recording flag, which causes the while loop to end. QProcess starts. But at the same time you end the recordThread() thread in which exactly this QProcess lives. And you expect that not only the QProcess survives, which it might do, but also all signal/slot connections remain intact?

I don't exactly know what happens with QProcess, possible races, blocking/non-blocking effects, but I bet your problem lies exactly in this area.

One more thing... I don't think it is healthy to create QProcess in thread A, but start it in thread B like you do.

I would try something like this (untested):

```
while(recording){
 //writing frame
}
QProcess p;
connect(&p,SIGNAL(finished(int)),this,SLOT(finishedFFMPEG()));
p.start(...your ffmpeg stuff...);
p.waitForFinished(-1);
```

and in finishedFFMPEG()

```
recordingThread->join(); recordingThread.reset();
```

Then the thread gets killed, when QProcess is done.

Comment: I really don't wan't to block the recordingThread() event until the QProcess is finished because I want a new recordingThread() to start while the QProcess from the previous thread is still running. I will probably create multiple recordingThreads() and block the event loop like you said to achieve this since it doesn't seem like there is another way

Comment: Your approach wasn't that wrong. Just don't put the QProcess into the same function, which you use to prepare the data and which you execute in another thread. Make your recordingThread() into two functions... one with the while loop, and one with QProcess and your are good.

Comment: Btw... my solution is good enough for you. The QProcess (or better the waitForFinished) is blocking, but only in this particular thread. Nothing stops you from creating more recordingThread() threads. Nothing is blocked in your main thread.

Comment: Hmm..I'm not getting what you mean with creating a own function for the QProcess. How will this function be called after finishing the task in recordThread()? Should I create a own thread for it?

Comment: As I said, you can keep the code like I pointed out. The blocking is local to the recordThread() and does not impair the rest of the program. If you don't like this, emit a signal right after the while loop. You can catch it in the main thread and start QProcess there. Again, kill your thread after you received this signal in the  slot. Currently you kill the thread before QProcess is done and sent the finished signal.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I think the problem is that I kind of have to kill the recordThread() before the QProcess finishes in order to achieve my goal of "I want a new recordThread() to start while the QProcess from the previous thread is still running". Thats why I think the only solution for this is to have multiple recordThread() std::threads.

Comment: I don't see your problem. Why do you have to kill one thread before you can start another one? Just because one recordThread() is running does not mean you cannot start a second one. And whether a QProcess is running in thread A has nothing to do with whatever happens in thread B.

Comment: You can start **recordingThread.reset(new std::thread(&Recorder::recordThread, this));** as often as you like. Of course with different recordingThread pointers and you must manage the different data sources and destinations. But this is self-evident. All those threads then have their own QProcess and you get from each a signal, when the processing is done. Again, you need some bookkeeping, which signal stems from which thread... but this is trivial.

Comment: Yes that's what I ment when I said I will have to use multiple recordThread() to make this work. So in my stop() function I will only set the boolean recording to false and I will then wait for the finished() signal to join and reset my thread, correct?

Comment: Exactly.  One of several possible ways to do what you want.   :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75717/discussion-between-testus-and-greenflow).